# jQuery Trigger mouseover event on newly created element

Tags: jquery

I wanted to trigger a mouseover event for an anchor tag(on the fly element)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a.new_element').on('trigger("mouseover")', function(){
        do_my_stuff_here();
    })
})
```

EDIT: Yes, I figured out how to attach mouseover event on that anchor element, what I wanted is to trigger the mouseover event after a certain element is created on the fly(During Page load).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `trigger("mouseover")` What is this...

Comment: Yes, the first parameter on the "on()" method should be the event name though, what I wanted to achieve is on how to trigger mouseover on anchor element on page load.

Comment: @Vincent - Oh so you are trying to trigger an event, not attaching an event,

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Part of, but I need to attach an event first(idk what's that event) an then trigger the mouseover on newly created anchor element.

Comment: @Vincent - So you want to both attach and trigger the `mouseover` event on newly created elements?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes, all I wanted is to trigger the mouseover event after a certain element is created on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach an event, use `.on`:

```
$("a.new_element").on("mouseover", ...);
```

To trigger an event on newly appended elements, use `.trigger`:

```
$("<a>").appendTo("body").trigger("mouseover");
```

If you really have to detect DOM change, use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```
$("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    //However, determining "new" elements is another challenge.
    //Maybe the new MutationObserver could help
    somehowYouHaveTheElementsList.trigger("mouseover");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this should be good enough, but the problem is "a.new_element" should have a method on() before you can trigger the mouseover event right?

Comment: @Vincent - Yes you will have to attach the `mouseover` event to it first before triggering it.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but in my case the newly created element was generated by a plugin(compulsory, strictly no code customization, poorly documented), and it was created on page load.

Comment: @Vincent - If you really have to trigger them as they are being added, use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$('a.new_element').on("mouseover", function(){
    do_my_stuff_here();
})
```

or if you meant [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) then you can do:

```
$('body').on("mouseover", 'a.new_element' , function(){
    do_my_stuff_here();
})
```